# unable to validate json schema for polymorphic object of array

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

Trying to validate below json against json schema for polymorphic type objects of array

Using dependency

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.networknt</groupId>
      <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.79</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

There are two types of vehicles, "bicycle" and "motorcycle" and person can have multiple vehicles

json with missing property "petName" for vehicle type "bicycle"

```
{
  "firstname" : "Jack",
  "lastname" : "Sparrow",
  "age" : "42",
  "vehicles" : [
    {
      "type" : "bicycle",
      "company" : "Hercules",
      "isElectric" : false
    },
    {
      "type" : "motorcycle",
      "company" : "Hero",
      "hp" : 340,
      "isRich" : true
    }
  ]
}
```

json-schema

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-06/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "required": [
        "firstname",
        "lastname",
        "age",
        "vehicles"
    ],
    "properties": {
        "firstname": {
            "type": "string",
            "minLength": 2,
            "maxLength": 10
        },
        "lastname": {
            "type": "string"
        },
        "age": {
            "type": [
                "integer",
                "string"
            ]
        },
        "vehicles": {
            "type": "array",
            "items": {
                "type": "object",
                "required": [
                    "type"
                ],
                "properties": {
                    "company": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "minLength": 2,
                        "maxLength": 10
                    },
                    "isElectric": {
                        "type": "boolean"
                    },
                    "hp": {
                        "type": [
                            "string",
                            "integer"
                        ]
                    },
                    "isRich": {
                        "type": "boolean"
                    },
                    "type": {
                        "type": "string",
                        "enum": [
                            "bicycle",
                            "motorcycle"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "additionalProperties": false
            },
            "anyOf": [
                {
                    "properties": {
                        "type": {
                            "const": "bicycle"
                        },
                        "vehicles": {
                            "items": {
                                "required": [
                                    "company",
                                    "isElectric",
                                    "petName"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                {
                    "properties": {
                        "type": {
                            "const": "motorcycle"
                        },
                        "vehicles": {
                            "items": {
                                "required": [
                                    "company",
                                    "hp",
                                    "isRich"
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "additionalProperties": false
    }
}
```

And as a result, there should be error for property "petName" not found in vehicle type "bicycle" as it is required field set for it but error is not raised. Is the json schema valid or am i missing something or have done any mistake?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues in your schema. Let's look at them one at a time.

1. `additionalProperties` should be moved up a level so it isn't inside `properties`.

```json
{
  "properties": {
    "firstname": { ... },
    "lastname": { ... },
    "age": { ... },
    "vehicles": { ... },
    "additionalProperties": false // <-- doesn't belong here
  }
}
```

2. `anyOf` is in the wrong place. You're adding constraints to the item, so put the `anyOf` on the item schema.

```json
{
  "properties": {
    "vehicles": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": { ... },
      "anyOf": [...] // <-- Move into `items`
    }
  }
}
```

3. The property schemas in the `anyOf` don't make sense because "type" and "vehicles" aren't in the same schema. Since the `anyOf` is in the item schema, its schemas should be written against the value in the item.

```json
{
  "properties": {
    "vehicles": {
      "items": {
        ...
        "anyOf": [
          {
            "properties": {
              "type": { "const": "bicycle" }
            },
            "required": ["company", "isElectric", "petName"]
          },
          {
            "properties": {
              "type": { "const": "motorcycle" },
            },
            "required": ["company", "hp", "isRich"]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

4. You've included "petName" as a required property for bicycles, but that property isn't defined for the vehicle schema and additional properties are not allowed. You either need to define a schema for "petName" or removed it from `required`

```json
{
  "properties": {
    "vehicles": {
      "items": {
        "properties": { // <-- No "petName" defined
          "company": { ... },
          "isElectric": { ... },
          "hp": { ... },
          "isRich": { ... },
          "type": { ... }
        },
        "additionalProperties": false, // <-- No additional properties allowed
        "anyOf": [
          {
            ...,
            "required": ["company", "isElectric", "petName"] // <-- Requires "petName"
          },
          { ... }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Once you fix those things, your schema should work as expected.